# Does Masters Theorem work where the coefficients are functions?

Tags: algorithm, analysis, equation-solving, theorem

I am learning about Masters Theorem and solving recurrence relations using it, but I can only find questions like:

T(n) = 16T(n/2) + 1

On google, where Masters Theorem is clearly applicable. I just came across a question:

T(n) = 2^(n/2) T(n/2) + 2^m

Can I apply Masters Theorem in such a case?

Comment: No, MT requires a constant number of subproblems, and also I believe you should have asked this question on another part of the stackexchange network, maybe https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Not as is, you first need something ad hoc like dividing through by 2^n and substituting T(n)/2^n = U(n). Then it applies to the U recurrence.